# Daterangepicker on google app script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I want to use daterangepicker for my google app from http://tamble.github.io/jquery-ui-daterangepicker/  site. I created two  files on google app script and copied the css and js files of the daterangepicker in to those files and included them to my index.html file. But the daterangepicker is not working. Is there anyway to include these daterangepickers' on google app script?

Thank you!
I have shared the link under https://script.google.com/macros/d/MrhGo_1c31wUG1ipFnV1d6I0YdntMo1yT/edit?uiv=2&mid=ACjPJvGKjyYmy6TM9TPrTFEjPnK1dd0qOVbVfgAjwqmn43cY8sdsLX0RqbAmLJQ541hwPhQwaR6ba3DETFk4MG9AHsjFg-W8eAP3M2z4CANF9onnqUC5McDuB-Rmtsp3IORmWXh4FEXiVBg

Thank you !

Comment: where is your code? you have to share the code that you implemented so far so that we can fix you.. or at least share the page with us to see

Comment: I have shared the link here. Thank you very much ! https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NW0hdagB9g9-bQ-7e-eimb5JrDA0Gx-baZB5tct_OzI/edit#gid=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to use this https urls not http..

I have fixed them for you and you can see the test page that is working just fine now :)

https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbxALmdG3mZXtcGD0R0DTwiduUPXqP7bazUDH0DjRg/dev

cheers, kres

Comment: also I see that console has one small issue,, for bootstrap you'll have to reference the newer jquery lib